# Is it possible to use Custom Delimiters from the Mustache.js command line tool?

Tags: node.js, mustache

I'm wondering if I can set custom delimiters with the Mustache command line tool.  It would seem possible because the documentation says this:

"The command line tool is basically a wrapper around Mustache.render so you get all the features."
Ref: https://developer.aliyun.com/mirror/npm/package/mustache

Also, per the documentation: "Set custom values by passing a new array of tags to render()..."  However, I'm not sure how to pass the new array into the command line tool?

Is it possible?

BTW, I'm running it on Windows, typically from a PowerShell console or script.